# Fetching rows using PHP OO Class

Tags: php, mysql, class

I have made a class function which will get rows from a table in my database along with an optional argument. This works when getting a single row however I cant get this to work when multiple rows are returned.

Here is what is in the Users class

```
public function getUsers($filter="") {
    $Database = new Database();
    if($filter == 'male') 
        $extra = "WHERE gender = 'm'";

    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM users 
            $extra";

    if ($Database->query($sql))
        return $Database->result->fetch_assoc();
    else
        return false;
}
```

Database Class

```
class Database {

    private $db = array();
    private $connection;
    private $result;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->connect();
    }

    public function connect() {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect('mysql.com', 'username', 'pass');
        mysqli_select_db($this->connection, 'database');
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        $this->result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql);
        return $this->result;
    }
```

This is the code used to try and display the rows

```
if ($student = $User->getUsers($filter)) {

    echo "<table>\n";   
    echo "<tr><td>Col 1</td><td>Col 2</td><td>Col 3</td><td>Col 4</td><td></td><td></td></tr>";

    foreach($student as $row) {       
       echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$row[col1]</td>";   
        echo "<td>$row[col2]</td>";   
        echo "<td>$row[col3]</td>";   
        echo "<td>$row[col4]</td>";   
        echo "<td>$row[col5]</td>";   
        echo "<td>$row[col6]</td>";   
       echo "</tr>\n";         
    }

    echo "</table>";        
    }
```

(I'm learning OO PHP, bear with me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still learning OOP but I have used this:

```
    protected $connection, $result, $_numRows;

    public function query($sql)
    {
    $this->result = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
    $this->_numRows = mysql_num_rows($this->result);
    }


    /*
    * @desc    get result af query
    *
    * @returns string $result
    */
    public function getResult()
    {
    return $this->result;
    }

    /*
    * @desc     Return rows in table
    * @returns int $_numRows
    */
    public function numRows()
    {
    return $this->_numRows;
    }

    /*
    * @desc     Count rows and add to array
    * @return string $rows array
    */
    public function rows()
    {
    $rows =array();
    for ($x=0; $x < $this->numRows(); $x++) {
        $rows[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($this->result);
    }
    return $rows;
    }
```

Then you could use something like this to get the rows:

```
public function getUsers($filter="") {
    $Database = new Database();
    if($filter == 'male') 
        $extra = "WHERE gender = 'm'";

    $sql = "SELECT *
            FROM users 
            $extra";
        if ($this->numRows() == 0) {
            echo "No rows found";
        } else {

        foreach ($this->rows() as $b) {
            $c = array('something' => $b['col']);
        }
        return $c;
    }
```

Modify the last part to suit your needs.

Comment: @Imran I have added some code above. I don't know if you got it working, but now the code is complete. I was a little tired when writing this yesterday. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear in your code where `$result` comes from...

You should call the fetch_assoc() method of an object returned by:

```
$mysqli->query($query)
```

Comment: Sorry the $result is incorrect, it doesnt lead to anything. I have a database class for queries, hence the use of $Database->query instead of $mysqli.

Comment: Please tidy up your code and maybe showing us your Database class will help to find the issue...

Comment: What does `print_r($student)` say?

Comment: it only returns the first row, not all rows. Updated to show the database class now by the way

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `$result->fetch_assoc()` twice? you are returning an array.. you should deal with `$student`.

Comment: Sorry I should have edited the while statement, there shouldnt of been another $result->fetch_assoc() there. I've tried foreach($student as $row) but this does not work.

Comment: fetch_assoc() returns only one row each time it's called. So you have to call it until there are no more rows: `Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row or NULL if there are no more rows.`